# is there a command that sends a redstone signal when a mob attacks a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know if it's a Testfor command or whatever. I want to use it for my horror map, so like there's going to be a zombie that chases you, and when he gets you, you get jumpscared.

Comment: First learn basic commands, then go on to big projects. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can link the damage that a player takes to a score of him:

```
/scoreboard objectives add damageTaken stat.damageTaken
```

Then you can test for players with a score in that scoreboard:

```
/say @a[score_damageTaken_min=1]
```

And then you have to reset it again so that it's ready to be used again:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_damageTaken_min=1] damageTaken 0
```

.

But in your case I would just test if a zombie is near a player:

```
/execute @e[type=zombie] ~ ~ ~ say @a[r=1]
```

Comment: For 1.13 replace `/execute @e[type=zombie] ~ ~ ~` with `/execute at @e[type=zombie]`. To get the exact same effect in 1.13 (the zombie writing in chat instead of the command block, use `/execute as @e[type=zombie] at @s`. Both in 1.12 and 1.13 this will list players twice who have two zombies in a 1 block radius around them. You have to see for yourself if you want that or not or if it can even happen. If it can happen and you don't want it, the command has to be changed.